# Removing comma and quotations when printing list

Tags: python, list

When I am printing the list, there is a comma and quotations in the letter X, how do I remove it?

```
#asks user input
m = int(input("Enter number of boxes horizontally and vertically: "))
n = int(input("Enter number of mines: "))
a=[]
for i in range(m):  
    a.append([])
    for k in range(m):
        a[i].append("X")
i=1
#prints the generated cells
for i in range(m):          
    print a[i]
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to use `join` to make your list in to a string. You want to make your string space separated, so you will want to use `' '.join()`:

Change this:

```
print a[i]
```

to this:

```
print(' '.join(a[i]))
```

Or, if you are mixing types, you should do:

```
' '.join(str(x) for x in a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: what if i want to put a number, will that function still work? i'm guessing it will only work with a string

Comment: When you append to your list just cast it to `str`.

Comment: now i am getting sequence item 0: expected string, bool found

Comment: Look at my updated answer. You should try doing that since it seems like you are playing with different types.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this:

```
print ' '.join(map(str, a[i]))
```

Comment: where can i put the newline so that it will look like a box?

Comment: modify "print a[i]" to this line.

Comment: it just prints the list in 1 line, i want it to print in m lines so that it will look like a cube, not just a single line

Comment: to print like a cube, try this `print ' '.join(map(str, a[i]))`